# How do I model the time series with only one but huge level shift into a VAR-Model?

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, mean-shift

I am about to analyze the relationship of several variables using a VAR/VECM-Model. But one of the series presents a massive level shift that occurs within one period (caused by policy change) like this: 0.3 0.4 0.3. 0.5 0.4 21 23 20 22 and so on. I wanted to make use of a Dummy but I´m not sure about how to add it and not to lose the information of the initial series. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

If you believe that *all* the characteristics of the series -- except for the level -- have remained the same throughout the sample period, including a dummy variable (valued zero before the changepoint and valued one at and after the changepoint) seems reasonable and natural. You will not lose information on the initial series by doing that (why would you?).

Whether the assumption that it was *only* the level that has changed is reasonable is another question. In your example it seems that not only the level but also the variance may have changed (increased).

Comment: Thanks for the comment! The series I put here is just randomly devised to give the example of the jump in the data. The real one may have the similar behavior (changed variance and so on) but it is not the question i address.

Comment: That was an answer (not a comment), but you are welcome! I don't know if I got you correctly, but it *is* important that the other characteristics (except for the level shift) of the time series stay the same if you are going to use a dummy.

Comment: What if I use two dummys? D1 = 1 for the first part of the series and D2 = 1 for the rest? So I put **b1D1X** and **b2D2X** instead of **bX** in the model, with X is the considered time series, b, b1 and b2 - coefficients to be estimated.  Will it work? It seems just like I have TWO variables to do a job of one)  
  
Sorry, I was to slowly to add my comment before

Comment: If you have two dummies, you will have to drop the constant. Otherwise your variables will be perfectly multicollinear. Using two dummies without a constant is equivalent to using one dummy with a constant; it is only the interpretation of the coefficient values that will change. But when you write **b1D1X**, do you mean interaction between the dummy and **X**? What I suggested so far was to include $\beta_1 D_1$ as an additive term in the model.

Comment: Writing **b1D1X** I meant that this part will vanish after changepoint because of D1=0 then. And vice versa for the second part. I wanted b1 to stay for the impact of the first part of X and b2 of the second one after the level shift. But you are right, modeled this way they are perfectly negative correlated.

Comment: Im my model I (and the economic theory) allow(s) all the variables to be endogenous, so I put X on the left hand side of my VAR model too. If I got it right, I should use the considered series unchanged on the LHS of the equation and _X + B1D1_ instead of initial one on the RHS of the model. After regression I will get b1(_X+B1D1_) and will have to calculate b1*(_B1_) to get the effect of the variable X after policy change (after jump)? Am I correct?

Comment: Without seeing the complete model I am not sure if I get you correctly. Anyway, the most straightforward and the simplest solution would be to include a dummy of the form (0,...,0,1,...,1) on the right hand side in each of the equations of the VAR model. Alternatively, include two complementary dummies but omit intercept. Other solutions would have different implications which may not be justified given the assumption that nothing besides the level of one variable changed at one point.